# WPF Binding Paths

Tags: c#, wpf

Someone please help me understand how my View is reaching my ViewModel.

My "BookView" has a Listview control that retrieves its data from a binding to a property in the "BookViewModel" using no namespaces. But the ViewModel is in a whole separate folder in the project so I wondering how it is finding it.

```
<UserControl x:Class="ContactBook.Views.BookView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ContactBook.Views"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800" Background="White">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ListView Grid.Column="0" 
                ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ContactsVM.Contacts}"
                SelectedItem="{Binding Path=ContactsVM.SelectedContact}">
            </ListView>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

This is my view model with the ContactVM property in it.

```
public class BookViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
        public ContactsViewModel ContactsVM
        {
            get { return _contactsVM; }
            set { OnPropertyChanged(ref _contactsVM, value); }
        }

        public BookViewModel()
        {

        }
    }
```

These 2 files are in different folders in the project.
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ys31R.jpg)

Comment: Are `BookViewModel` and `BookView` in the same namespace? Are you using a tool like [Caliburn Micro](https://caliburnmicro.com/) that finds models/viewmodels based on view name?

Comment: How do you know what namespace a xaml file is in? And no I am not using any MVVM frameworks.

Comment: The project folder structure is not related to namespaces. This is not Java. And the view does not "find" the view model. You have assigned an instance of the view model class to the DataContext of the view. That is how the view and the view model are connected.

Comment: But where is the data context specified? The data context of the Listview control is not stated nor is it inherited from any parent control. And the Source property of the binding is not stated either.

Comment: The DataContext property value is in fact inherited by child elements. There should be something like `DataContext = new BookViewModel();` in the code behind of your MainWindow. A UserControl in that window would inherit the DataContext, and so would the elements in its XAML.

Comment: In my main "AppViewModel" I do set an object "CurrentView" to a "BookViewModel", so I guess it could be that. I am following a tutorial on Youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bmw68zxjwG4&t=28s